# What path should be used to write to iPhone's memory?

Tags: ios, swift, saving-data

i am trying to save a string to device's memory for a simple to do app. It works great on a simulator where i set the path for writing to memory to be - let path: String = directory + "App4.txt". But when running this on an actual iPhone it doesn't save to memory.

This is the function.

```
    if let directory: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first { 

    let path: String = directory + "App4.txt"

    userInputString = userInput.joinWithSeparator("-")

    // Writing.
    do {
        try userInputString.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")// Error handling here.
    }
    }
```

Any help is very much appreciated!! :)

Comment: Add `print(path)` to your program and inspect the output. Can you spot the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Martin-R is alluding to, you need to have a `"/"` in your path between `directory` and the file name.

Comment: Thank you so much, would have never spotted it otherwise!